# Can bloom filter be used to filter UTXO?

Tags: utxo, bip37-bloom-filter

I am thinking about building an spv-like wallet using trusted nodes.
It does not download blockchain.
Instead, the wallet gets its utxo, transactions,balance data from abe.

My question is, can the bloom filter be used to filter UTXO?

Comment: Have you read [BIP37](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0037.mediawiki)?

Comment: You certainly could do this, but it would be much slower on the server's side than a per-address query, and I don't think there's a ready-made implementation to do this.

Comment: What would be the benefit over regular SPV wallets? They don't download the blockchain either.

Comment: Do you mean filtering all data on Abe with your filter? If you're using Abe I don't see why you need to worry about bloom filters or SPV.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see your desired trusted full node setup.

But if you can control a the trusted full-nodes, you might consider using the [REST `getutxo`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/0.11/doc/REST-interface.md#query-utxo-set) command. It's more or less similar to a not implemented [Bip64](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0064.mediawiki). In my opinion you don't need bloom filter for the `getutxo` command.

Don't expose the `REST`/`RPC` interface to the public. Instead build a [reverse proxy with apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) or similar.